# JSON Validation for IIB ( IBM Integration Bus)

Tags: json, validation, parsing, ibm-integration-bus

I'm trying to create a JSON validator for IIB(IBM Integration Bus) as i cannot use any of the third party existing JSON Validation APIs available over the Internet. So far i've an idea of converting JSON data to XML & JSON schema into XSD, perform the validation.

Will the above approach cause any problems or do i need to explore on creating a parser which breaks down data into tokens & validate (which i came to know is very hard to create) ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a anything, IIB support JSON validation trough Swagger which is the contract for REST services [Swagger in IIB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bi12018_.htm).
You could write the Swagger document in JSON or YAML (The last one supported since 10.0.0.7). If you are more familiar with XSDs you can build one, then use some online converter to convert your XSD to JSON (search for "xml to json") and finally use it in your Swagger definition.

Answer (score 0):

Schema Validation consumes a considerable CPU processing. If you want to parsing JSON to XML and then validate you´re going to consumes more CPU.

You can create a Java Compute and use a third party library (without going to the internet) to use a JSON Schema to validate.

[JSON Schema Validator!](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer & i agree, but my client doesn't want me to use third party code in its services.Any other approach u can recommend